# Is there an Umbraco dynamic table property editor?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

Is it possible to have a property editor on a document type in Umbraco that acts similar to a spreadsheet?

My goal is to pre-define 3 or 4 columns (Field Label, Text..) and allow the Umbraco user to add rows as they wish. My ASP.NET page will then loop through the rows and build the content based on the rows

Ideally the table could also be sortable

Is this a property editor already available or does anyone know of any custom ones?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking but it's possible to define 1 to multiple content by using [nested content](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/) or [archetype](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/archetype/)

You can define the "columns" in a document type and create a list of documenttypes to create the rows